# Filtering by non-key field in DynamoDB (aws-cli)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

​i'm trying to query a number field in DynamoDB through aws-cli. 
It forces me to set the key (userId) to be something, although I want to retrieve all the users where the queriedField equals to 0. this is the syntax:
​

```
aws dynamodb query
--table-name TableName
--key-condition-expression "userId = :userid" 
--filter-expression "mapAttr.queriedField = :num"
--expression-attribute-values '{ ":userid": { "S": "<AccountID>" }, ":num" : { "N": "0" }}'
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do this query, you will have to [`scan`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Scan.html) the whole table with your filter expression.

However, if this is for something that is still in development/design, consider making the 'number field' a top level attribute.  That will allow you to create a GSI with a hash key of 'number field', and project the userId attribute to the GSI. Alternatively, you can use [Global Secondary Index Write Sharding for Selective Table Queries](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/bp-indexes-gsi-sharding.html)

Comment: thank you.
For anyone else struggling with this, here's a snippet of the solution:  
`aws dynamodb scan --table-name TableName --filter-expression "mapAttr. queriedField = :num" --expression-attribute-values '{ ":num" : { "N": "0" }}'`